# How to lazy open resource and eagerly release?

Tags: haskell

How can I provide a lazily acquired resource of any kind so that client code has following guarantees:

- Resource is allocated at most once and not before first use (possibly never depending on business logic)
- Resource is released as soon as it is guaranteed to be not needed (alternatively, release on "exit")
- Such construct can be nested within another in isolation except shared resource pool

Intuition tells me that it should be possible to define DSL that captures this idea without IO which I will later provide as part of main interpreter.

What fundamental abstractions can capture those needs?

Comment: [pipes](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pipes) and [conduit](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit) comes to mind (but I think the question is not really a good fit for SO - as you are basically asking for a library - sorry)

Comment: @Carsten Agreed, I removed that part of question, I care mainly about picking best abstractions before implementing them.

Comment: Sounds a lot like `ResourceT` from [`resourcet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/resourcet).

Comment: [**`seq`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:seq) might be a simple solution, depending on the usage...

Comment: One solution might be regions. See e.g. [Oleg's page about regions](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/resource-aware-prog/region-io.pdf).